# Why is document insertion slow in CPF enabled database in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic

I have a MarkLogic 7 server in which I am trying to insert documents.

1. When I insert **10000** documents in a database that does not has CPF installed it takes **2.18** seconds as shown below: [image: Document Insertion with no CPF]
2. Now, I install CPF on the database **local-db** with enable conversion as false:
   [image: Install CPF with enable conversion false]
3. After this I set the default domain scope to collection **tasks** and then insert **10000** documents. It now takes **3 minutes 35 seconds**[image: Document insertion with CPF]

Can anyone help me understand why is the document insertion taking so long?

Is there any option by which this can be optimized?

Answer (score 3):

CPF works through a series of pre-commit and post-commit triggers, so that adds additional load to the system. The conversion itself will happen in the post-commit trigger.

One thing you might try is smaller batches of commits. If you do 10 transactions of 1000 documents each, does it change the timings? If so, you could experiment with your batch size to tune for the best performance.

Answer (score 3):

Also note that CPF wasn't designed to be fast, but robust. CPF builds on top of Triggers, and it will cause multiple triggers to get executed for *each* document. It keeps track of state in document properties, so it also creates additional database fragments. All this causes it to be able to survive restarts though, which is particularly useful if you have a lot of processing of which you need to be sure it gets done without looking after it yourself.

If you want to ingest data as fast as possible including transforms, then consider using MLCP with transforms..

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

CPF triggers may be enough to explain the difference. But also check your OS to see what the bottleneck is: probably CPU or disk I/O. Check to make sure you aren't under memory pressure during the transaction. If the operating system is paging out, that will hurt performance quite a bit.

Comment: I am working on a machine with SSD disk and quad core CPU running windows 7. When I insert the 10000 documents into the CPF enabled collection the CPU utilization remains under **40%**. I think the processing which happens in background to move a document in *cpf:state initial* is taking time. Can I consider disabling any of the triggers that get created at the time of CPF installation?

Comment: You haven't figured out what the bottleneck is yet. The CPU utilization suggests that it might be lock-bound, but you don't know until you rule out the disk. Saying "it's SSD" doesn't help.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out what is causing the document insertion to be slow. But on same environment when I uninstall CPF from the database it takes around 2 seconds.